# summarizing hierarchical data using wildcard strings

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given hierarchical data, where each entry has a main category f1, a subcategory f2, and a subsubcategory f3, and an outcome y. For instance, we could be looking at person data, where each entry corresponds to a unique individual, f1=country, f2=province, f3=city where the person was born, and y=binary value indicating whether a person has a specific gene.
Here's a small example:

```
   f1 f2 f3  y
0   1  A  a  0
1   1  A  b  1
2   1  B  c  1
3   1  B  a  1
4   2  A  a  0
5   2  A  c  0
6   2  B  d  0
```

What I would like to do is summarize this data based on the outcome y, using wildcards '*'.

```
   f1 f2 f3  y s
0   1  A  a  0 1.A.a
1   1  A  b  1 1.A.b
2   1  B  c  1 1.B.*
3   1  B  a  1 1.B.*
4   2  A  a  0 2.*.*
5   2  A  c  0 2.*.*
6   2  B  d  0 2.*.*
```

In the table above, I created a summary column s. Here entries 4, 5 and 6 are all represented as `'2.*.*'` since all entries with f1=2 have y=0, independent of subcategories f2 and f3. Similarly, 2 and 3 can be represented as `'1.B.*'` since the outcome y for f1=1,f2=B is always 1, independent of the value of f3. An extreme edge case arises if all outcomes y are the same. In that case we would represent every entry by `*.*.*`.

Question is how to efficiently build this summary column. I presume I can somehow achieve this using groupby statements but I am not entirely sure how. Note that this example is limited to 3 categories f1,f2,f3 and y is limited to be binary, but in practice there may be more categories, and more possible outcome values in y.

The code to produce the above table:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'f1': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'f2': ['A','A','B','B','A','A','B'],
                   'f3': ['a','b','c','a','a','c','d'],
                   'y': [0,1,1,1,0,0,0]})
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code achieves the desired goal. The code first builds a decision tree to assign the right label to each row. This tree is computed in a recursive manner. Once the tree is computed, the relabel function uses this tree to compute the desired labels for the provided data frame.

The recursive comp_label_map function builds the decision tree. It recursively splits the data into smaller blocks, until for a given block all `y` values are the same.

```
import pandas as pd

# Compute a decision tree that can be used to map rows to their final labels
def comp_label_map(df, categories, goal, prefix, index):
    # Base case: all rows in the df block have the same goal (y) value.
    if df[goal].nunique()==1:
        return prefix+"".join(['*.']*(len(categories)-index))
    if index > len(categories):
        raise RuntimeError('Ran out of categories')

    # else, we must have different values, keep splitting
    groups=df.groupby(categories[index])
    level = {}
    for name, group in groups:
        level[name]=comp_label_map(group,categories,goal,prefix+str(name)+'.',index+1)
    return level

def relabel(row, categories,relabel_map):
    tree_node=relabel_map['_']
    for category in categories:
        #check whether tree_node is a dict. If not we reached a leaf of the decision tree
        if not isinstance(tree_node,dict): 
            return tree_node
        #not a leaf, we must check whether we can go deeper. Test wheter theres a mapping for this category
        if not row[category] in tree_node:
            return 'Not Defined'

        tree_node=tree_node[row[category]]

    return tree_node


df = pd.DataFrame({'f1': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'f2': ['A','A','B','B','A','A','B'],
                   'f3': ['a','b','c','a','a','c','d'],
                   'y': [0,1,1,1,0,0,0]})

print(df) #df before
relabel_map={ '_':comp_label_map(df,['f1','f2','f3'],'y', '', 0)}
df['relabeled']=df.apply(lambda row: relabel(row, ['f1','f2','f3'], relabel_map),axis=1)
print(relabel_map)
print(df) #df after
```

The result:

```
   f1 f2 f3  y s
0   1  A  a  0 1.A.a
1   1  A  b  1 1.A.b
2   1  B  c  1 1.B.*
3   1  B  a  1 1.B.*
4   2  A  a  0 2.*.*
5   2  A  c  0 2.*.*
6   2  B  d  0 2.*.*
```

The corresponding decision tree:

```
{'_': 
    {1: 
        {'A': 
            {'a': '1.A.a.', 
             'b': '1.A.b.'
            }, 
         'B': '1.B.*.'
        }, 
     2: '2.*.*.'
    }
}
```

Note: the very first key `_` acts as the root node. If all values `y` are identical across all rows, then the decision tree will simply be `{'_':'*.*.*}`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most adaptable implementation, but will do the trick - and be faster than `for` loop ;)

```py
df[["f1", "f2", "f3"]]=df[["f1", "f2", "f3"]].astype(str)

#count unique y-s for different groups.

dfgr1=df.groupby("f1")["y"].nunique()
dfgr2=df.groupby(["f1", "f2"])["y"].nunique()

#build summary based on cascading number of unique elements within different groups

df["s"]=np.where(dfgr1.loc[df["f1"]].eq(1), df["f1"]+".*.*", np.where(dfgr2.loc[zip(df["f1"], df["f2"])].eq(1), df["f1"].str.cat(df["f2"], sep=".")+".*", df["f1"].str.cat(df[["f2", "f3"]], sep=".")))
```

Outputs:

```py
  f1 f2 f3  y      s
0  1  A  a  0  1.A.a
1  1  A  b  1  1.A.b
2  1  B  c  1  1.B.*
3  1  B  a  1  1.B.*
4  2  A  a  0  2.*.*
5  2  A  c  0  2.*.*
6  2  B  d  0  2.*.*
```